# Latex error while compiling

Tags: errors

While compiling the tex file I am getting the following error message

```
Missing number treated as zero.
(to be read again)
                 \hfil
1.69 \newpage
```

Comment: That isn't really enough information to help, it just means tex was expecting to find a number (eg a font size or length or setting a counter or...) and it found `\hfil` which is not a number. So the error is before this point.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us more information as David Carlisle requests.

Answer (score 1):

You have a construct such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\count4=\expandafter\hfil
\newpage

\end{document}
```

which is a *complete, reproducible*, example that produces

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \hfil 
l.6 \newpage

?
```

Specifically you have got a construct (`\count4=` here) that is looking for a number but instead sees `\hfil`  which accounts for the first three lines of the error message, combined with a construct (`\expandafter` here) that has made TeX look ahead so that it has already seen the `\newpage` on line 6 (or 69 in your case) before it has detected the error, which accounts for the fourth line of the error message.

So the real cause of the error is whatever is around line 68 of your document.